# What determines the communication speed? is it the physical link's speed or the communication card speed?

Tags: communication, solid-state-relay, time

Two IEDs (Intelligent Electronic Device),an electronic relay and a gateway, are connected with  Modbus RTU protocol over RS232.

- In the relay's manual it states that a speed of 9200 bauds can be selected (typical for modbus serial)
- In the gateway's Manual, I found that the communication card is rated at 115 kbps (actually I was considering two gateways, one with communication speed 115kbps and the other with 38 kbps)

My question is at what speed these two IEDs will communicate? is it 9600 bauds, or 115kbps (or 38 kbps)?

Comment: Whats the maximum speed of the slowest device. That's your answer.

Answer (score 3):

RS232 is an "asynchronous" serial protocol, which means that the communications clock signal isn't directly wired from one unit to the other.  Instead, each unit is "told" the speed at which it should communicate.  If both units are set to 9600 bps, for example, then the receiving unit will sample the data lines at just the right time to intercept the signals coming from the transmitting unit.  This allows bidirectional communication with only two wires (plus ground).

So, for your system, you want to choose any speed that both units can achieve.  The gateway is rated to 115kbps, but you can configure it to operate more slowly.  If the relay only communicates at 9600, then you'll have to set the gateway to 9600, also.

Comment: I'm curious about what will happen if I set the two devices to communicate at a speed greater than the speed (bandwidth) allowed by the physical link between them.

Comment: @Heisenberg For the communication to work, the receiver has to be able to reliably detect a high or low state on the data line. The maximum speed possible for this type of serial link is going to be dictated by quality of cable construction, more than an actual electrical limit.  If the cable is poorly shielded, for example, then externally-coupled noise can become a problem.  Or, if the cable is too capacitive, then the signals won't rise (or fall) fast enough.  If this happens, then the receiver will sample the line before it has reached the desired voltage level...

Comment: @Heisenberg What do you think happens if the devices try to communicate at a speed greater than the speed allowed by the link? By definition of the words "speed", "greater", and "allowed", the communications will fail. The exact failure mode is unpredictable based on the information supplied.